# Tensorflow to ONNX conversion

Tags: python, tensorflow, uwp, darkflow, onnx

I'm currently trying to convert a saved (and working) .pb file that I created with this tutorial (https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow) into a onnx file. I'm using winML tools at the moment but the result of the conversion doesn't work at all (the input parameters are wrong + the whole architecture is not correct).

My input parameter (as specified on the very bottom of the readme): input:0

Output node: ouput:0

I want to use the converted model inside a UWP application that's running on a HoloLens.

Has anyone already successfully converted this model (or any TensorFlow model) to ONNX?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx) to convert your .pb file to onnx.

Install it using pip.

```
pip install tf2onnx
```

Then you call it like this.

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --input <path to your pb file> --inputs <comma-delimited input names goes here> --outputs <comma-delimited output names goes here> --output <path to output in onnx format>
```

You said your input is `input:0` and your ouput is `ouput:0`, so the command should look like this.

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --input yolo.pb --inputs input:0 --outputs ouput:0 --output yolo.onnx
```

If necessary, you can use the [netron](https://netron.app/) app to verify the input and output name.

Answer (score 3):

I converted several models from TF to onnx with [MMdnn](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn)

Also, [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx) can be usefull

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.