# Trained tensorflow model used in .NET framework

Tags: python, c#, .net, visual-studio, tensorflow

I used Google Colab to build a 1-D Convoluted Neural Network (CNN) model using Tensorflow (it is a multi-class, multi-label model).  I would now like to take that saved model (for example the pb file) and make predictions inside of a .NET Framework using C# (Visual Studio).  So I would like to do the following inside a .NET Framework (this is obviously really stripped down):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('pb_model')

model.predict(data)
```

I haven't seen an easy solution for Tensorflow 1-D CNN model (which would just be load a Tensorflow library into the .NET Framework.

I've seen the ML.NET where they use transfer learning of a Tensorflow image classification model to begin their learning [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification#run-the-application).

I recently came across Tensorflow.NET on GitHub [link](https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET).  This seems to be the best avenue as they aim to implement Tensorflow in C# for .NET developers.  However this builds a model and then tests it all inside the .NET framework; therefore it does not address how to take a trained 1-D CNN model from python and make predictions in the .NET framework.

Has anyone come across a similar problem and what did you do (or what would you suggest)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [LostTech.TensorFlow aka Gradient](https://losttech.software/gradient.html) to call pretty much any TensorFlow API from C#.

```
using tensorflow;

var model = tf.keras.models.load_model("pb_model");
model.predict(data);
```

More samples [here](https://github.com/losttech/Gradient-Samples)

disclaimer: I am one of the authors.

Comment: I do like your solution; however this will be pushed onto a device with limited storage capacity.  Therefore with the requirement to use TF and Python as dependencies, I'm thinking it will be too much.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question then. ML.NET supports ONNX models, so one option is to convert to ONNX. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214470/tensorflow-to-onnx-conversion